# ruby docusign api download completed signed document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, download, document, docusignapi

I am trying to download each completed document signed using docusign_rest gem, but there is no where is documentation about how to do it.

The following [post](http://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-API-Integration-Ruby-Salesforce-and-Other-READ-ONLY/FAQ-What-is-in-the-SDK/td-p/819) says that DocuSign Web Services API 3.0 SDK can Retrieve the completed PDF for each separate document in an envelope.

Does docusign_rest support v3 of docusign SDK?

I did google search many times but not found a post where I could download the completed document using ruby.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The latest version (0.3.1) of the [docusign_rest gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/docusign_rest) now has a [get_combined_document_from_envelope method](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/docusign_rest/0.3.1/DocusignRest/Client#get_combined_document_from_envelope-instance_method) method that will return the combined document.

Comment: Please note that this is not a official DocuSign gem. Please see the official DocuSign [Github](https://github.com/docusign/) page for  supported libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe DocuSign has an official Ruby gem/SDK so I'm guessing you're using a community developed one?  If so please link to it.

If that gem does not allow the downloading of completed documents you can just add it in.  It's just one REST API call to download a completed doc, see this page from the API Documentation:

[Retrieving Envelopes and Documents](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#Basic%20Scenarios/Retrieving%20Envelope%20and%20Documents.htm)

The call is just a simple GET request to the `/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined` URI.  The raw request would look something like this:

```
GET http://{server}/restapi/{apiVersion}/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined

X-DocuSign-Authentication: <DocuSignCredentials><Username>{name}</Username><Password>{password}</Password><IntegratorKey>{integrator_key}</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>
Accept: application/pdf
Content-Type: application/json
```